# React 'Set is undefined', on Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sharepoint, set, undefined

I'm getting this error...

```
SCRIPT5009: 'Set' is undefined
File: require-951f856e.js, Line: 1, Column: 1662
```

...on a Sharepoint site I developed for work. I have absolutely no idea what this means, other than somewhere in a React file there is a set that is not getting defined.

This results in my site partly loading in Internet Explorer, but the contents of an iframe do not load. The site is working perfectly in firefox and chrome.

I can't find any help elsewhere. Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Set` is a data structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). It is part of the ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) spec and only [supported in IE 11 and above](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Browser_compatibility) (with partial support in IE11).

You should provide a polyfill for orlder IE versions.

Examples:

- https://github.com/zloirock/core-js (recommended)
- https://github.com/WebReflection/es6-collections
- https://github.com/medikoo/es6-set

---

**Update, per comments:**

> I'm running this on IE11. I don't understand why it is still seeing this.

Perhaps you are running on older document/compatibility modes. I suggest you open the console (F12) and check it out.

A workaround for this would be to add

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

to the `<head>` of the page. It would **force** the compatibility mode to edge when available.

Comment: I'm running this on IE11. I don't understand why it is still seeing this.

Comment: Perhaps you are running on older document/compatibility modes. I suggest you open the console (F12) and check it out.

Comment: Holy schnitzel, you're a life saver. This worked! I haven't had this problem in the entire time I've been developing the site but I just released it today and this happened. Could one of the users browsers have made a difference?

Comment: Humm.. I'm sorry, I don't really understand what did you mean by *Could one of the users browsers have made a difference?*. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Anyhow, I suggest, if you haven't already, you add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />` to the `head`. It would force the compatibility mode.

Comment: Yes, so today was the first day that I shared this site with other people. I have tested it many times on IE with no problem, but just today after sharing it with other people, did the iframes in my home page not work.

Comment: Heh, it happens. Good thing it's worked out. I have summarised some of the comments everything in the answer.

Comment: You can also use the core-js npm package, and import the core-js/es/map and core-js/es/set. That should do the job, no matter of IE10 or IE11.